# strtotime returning false

Tags: php

I have datestrings that looks like this:

```
"2012 28 Nov 21:00 CET"
```

`strtotime("2012 28 Nov 21:00 CET")` return false.

Is there any way to convert this string in to a date object, or do I need to format it differently?

Comment: Try using [`date_parse_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php).

Comment: Where are you getting the string-date from?

Comment: @phpisuber01 Extracting it from a html page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`2012 28 Nov 21:00 CET` is weird date/time format. Y-D-M? Where are you getting that?

At any rate, the DateTime object has a method `createFromFormat` that will do a better job parsing that:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y d M H:i T", '2012 28 Nov 21:00 CET');
$ts = $dt->getTimestamp();
echo $ts; // 1354132800
```

Try it here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NfAmcw

`strtotime` expects a "English textual datetime" [(according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)), which Y-D-M is not. Any time `strtotime` returns false, it simply doesn't understand your string, which in this application is expected. A note on the manual page deals with this issue:

> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

That's just as well, `DateTime` is a superior tool for any interaction with dates or times.

**Documentation**

- `DateTime` class- http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
- `DateTime::createFromFormat` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
- `strtotime` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- `date` (also lists date format strings) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

[strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) doesn't create a date object, it simply tries to parse your input and returns a unix timestamp.

You can find valid formats here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

```
echo strtotime("2012-11-28T21:00:00+01:00");
```

would output `1354132800`

to create a php [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) object you could do this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-11-28T21:00:00+01:00');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```