# how to convert any date to specific format in php?

Tags: php

I created a function where i pass **different format of dates**, I want to convert **any date format** to specific format that i defined.

```
function change_date_format($date)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
    return $date;
}

print_r(change_date_format('28/02/2012'));
```

This format of date return ***1970-01-01***

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: How would you solve "any date format"? If you pass in: `08/02/2019`, would that be August 2 or February 8? You need restrictions or at least pass what format it is as a second argument. Then you can use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: @M.Hemant yes i got error, see i edit my question

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so what is the solution for that. any solution appreciated

Comment: please refer this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614500/strtotime-returning-false/13614677]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ***@Magnus Eriksson*** suggested is, to send format as a parameter and then use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
<?php

function change_date_format($givenDate,$format)
{
    $date = date_create_from_format($format, $givenDate);
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
}

print_r(change_date_format('08/02/2012','d/m/Y'));
echo PHP_EOL;
print_r(change_date_format('08/02/2012','m/d/Y'));
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/SlNtA